# Are there anyway I can change color of Y axises when using zedgraph?

Tags: colors, axis, zedgraph

I need to change exactly color of Y axises and their text descriptions, but can't find anything related with this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
 GraphPane myPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;
 myPane.YAxis.Title.FontSpec.FontColor = Color.Green;
 myPane.YAxis.MajorGrid.Color = Color.LightGreen;
 zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();
```